# Keep Track of changes in Cell A1 in Cell B1 Cell A2 in Cell B2 and so on

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to keep track of changes of Cell A1 in Cell B1 cell A2 in cell B2 and so on....

```
For Ex initially 
Cell A1 & Cell B1 should be Blank
If Cell A1=9/14/2017 & Cell B1 should be having a Drop down with Blank
If Cell A1=9/21/2017 & Cell B1 Should be having a Drop down with 9/14/2017
If Cell A1=9/28/2017 & Cell B1 Should be having a Drop down with 9/14/2017 & 9/21/2017
If Cell A1=10/08/2017 & Cell B1 Should be having a Drop down with 9/14/2017 , 9/21/2017 & 9/28/2017
```

and So On..
The values of column A will be given by me manually based on my requirement in date format(mm/dd/yyyy).

The same with 
A2 & B2
A3 & B3 & so On.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thanks for Editing the Question

Comment: It's possible using VBA and Worksheet change, are you opposed to using VBA?

Comment: I can use VBA but not in another sheet in same sheet I required

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work, just add it into the VBA Code for the sheet where you enter all the data.  There are a few things that you will need to setup

- A new sheet called "Data"
- In this new sheet, you will need to add columns with the heading HISTA1, HISTA2, HISTA3 etc.
- You will then need to define these columns as named ranges with the same name as the header you gave them (in the code I went up to 6 columns, but you can add extra lines to the code if you need more
- For Cells B1, B2, B3 etc in the entry sheet, you will need to add Data Validation lists, and reference the correct named range.  E.g in Cell B1 the range would be "=HISTA1"

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, x, newval, hist As Long
  Dim data As Worksheet

  Set data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet


  If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

  x = Target.Row
  newval = Target.Value
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Undo
  hist = Target.Value

  y = data.Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row

  data.Cells(y + 1, x).Value = hist

  Target.Value = newval


  a = data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  b = data.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  c = data.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  d = data.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  e = data.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  f = data.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  ActiveWorkbook.Names("HISTA1").Delete
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("HISTA2").Delete
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("HISTA3").Delete
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("HISTA4").Delete
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("HISTA5").Delete
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("HISTA6").Delete

  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="HISTA1", RefersTo:="=Data!$A$2:$A$" & a
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="HISTA2", RefersTo:="=Data!$B$2:$B$" & b
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="HISTA3", RefersTo:="=Data!$C$2:$C$" & c
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="HISTA4", RefersTo:="=Data!$D$2:$D$" & d
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="HISTA5", RefersTo:="=Data!$E$2:$E$" & e
  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="HISTA6", RefersTo:="=Data!$F$2:$F$" & f


  Application.EnableEvents = True
  End Sub
  ```

I based the code on your example, but if the cell references are different then the code will need to be amended, as the entry row is linked to the history column.

Any questions or issues, am happy to help.